# very low speed in fact no pick up at all and lot of vibration of my ford fiesta diesel

Tags: engine, power, steering, oil-leak

I don't know how to maintain a Ford Fiesta diesel car's engine which has lot of noise with no pick up and power steering oil leakage.

My car has lot of problems like pick up, speed, mileage, rattling noise, power steering oil leakage problems.

Comment: As written, there's not much we can do for you. Please, let's start with a single issue (of your choice), tell us what you've done to figure it out, and what exactly the symptoms are behind it. We'll need more information about the car itself: year/mileage/engine ... you've already supplied some of the information, but it's no where being complete. Let's get one problem knocked out and it may solve some of your other issues along the way. If it doesn't, ask the second question and so forth. Welcome to the site! I hope we can help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are starting the journey investigating how your car works and how to maintain it properly.  Awesome.

I recommend that you start the trip with the purchase of a service manual (either Haynes or Chiltons) They run about $30 USD.  That book will help you understand how things work.  They provide troubleshooting guides for repairing issues.

In your case, I'd skim thru the book, take a complete inventory of your cars performance state for each of chapters of the book.  You are going to prepare a "things to do" list for your car.

An other alternative is to take the car to a mechanic and have them perform an assessment survey on your car. They will provide you with a comprehensive list of things that need service or repair.

That list will have to be prioritized.  Obviously safety related items need to get fixed immediately.  Work down the list one item at a time.  Go slow, accumulate tools as you need them.  You don't need to complete every repair at once.  Spend some time understanding what can go wrong.

My three rules for working on cars:

- Never work on the car that you have to drive to work tomorrow.
- Focus on your safety.  Always ask the question, what could possibly happen here?  ... will I get hurt? (ask me about my cutting a fuel line with welding torch while laying underneath a car experience...)
- When you get tired and pissed off and things aren't going smoothly, take a real hard look at the wrench in your hand.  Stare at it for a moment.  Then throw the wrench as hard as you can at the back wall of the garage, close the garage door and go home.  You are done for the day.